# Group action of the Baumslag-Solitar groups

Tags: group-theory, linear-transformations, group-actions, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

The Baumslag-Solitar groups are defined by

$$G=BS(m,n)=\langle a,b: ba^{m}b^{-1}=a^{n}\rangle\,,$$

where $m,n$ are integers.

My question is: Is there a linear action of $G=BS(1,2)$ over $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ ?

Comment: Equip $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual $(x,y)$-coordinate system.  Perhaps, you can take $a$ to be the counterclockwise rotation about the origin by $\dfrac{2\pi}{3}$ and $b$ the reflection about the line $y=0$.  This group action is unfortunately not faithful.

Comment: Thank you so much  for your answer

Comment: I believe you can find this in Meier's book "Graphs, groups and trees". (Unfortunately I cannot find an online version, any my copy is socially distancing itself from me by sitting on my bookcase in my locked work office.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the matrices $\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ generate a copy of $BS(1,2)$. So this gives an action on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you guys give me some books references to self learning groups actions and representation group theory?

Comment: Google linear groups, books - for infinite discrete groups. For representations of finite groups, the number of books is enormous.

Comment: By the way....I understood that these matrices generate a copy of $G=BS(1,2)$. But still don´t see how to make $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ a $G-$module. I mean ...if $g$ belongs to $G$ and x belongs to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$...how to define gx?

Comment: $g$ is a product of matrices $A_1A_2...A_n$. Then $gx= A_1A_2...A_nx$.

Comment: Ok, that is obvius. Thank you so much

Comment: An other question:  for which values of n is BS(1,n) a free group? is B(1,2) free?

Comment: If $n\ne 0$ then the group is solvable of class 2 or Abelian of rank 2 and hence not free. If $n=0$ then the group is infinite cyclic, hence free of rank 1.

Comment: @Jose A one relator group $\langle \mathbf{x}\mid R=1\rangle$ is free if and only if the relator $R$ is a primitive element of $F(\mathbf{x})$, which is easily decided via Whitehead's algorithm. For two-generator, one-relator groups (as is the case here), Cohen, Metzler and Zimmerman, in their paper "What does a basis of $F(a,b)$ look like?", gave a super-simple characterisation of primitive elements of $F(a,b)$, and in particular a reduced and cyclically reduced primitive element contains $b$ or $b^{-1}$ or neither, but not both. Hence, no word $b^{-1}a^mba^n$ is primitive.

Comment: Whoops! Yes, that should be "a word $b^{-1}a^mba^n$ is primitive if and only if $m=0$ and $|n|=1$, or $|m|=1$ and $n=0$".